# Making a Portfolio on Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css

Hello I am attempting to create a Portfolio using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. My only previous experience is making a basic website with standard text and a light\dark theme button. I am trying to get my Title the be on the left of my navigation bar, and my directories to be on the left side of the navigation bar. Could Someone explain how i would do this.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* navbar styling */
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: crimson;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.navbar .maxwidth{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar .logo a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar .menu li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar .menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="logo"><a href='#'>Portfo<span>lio.</span></a></div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider starting with something like Bootstrap, so you can see how they do it. Flexbox will be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing it pretty much correctly. Your css had a typo. I changed `maxwidth` to `max-width`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* navbar styling */
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: crimson;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.navbar .max-width{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar .logo a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar .menu li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar .menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="logo"><a href='#'>Portfo<span>lio.</span></a></div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```